# Etymology of "pfiesteria"?

Tags: etymology

I was playing this spelling bee game when this word came up and I wanted to know how the word was formed but could not find anything and thought perhaps someone on this site could help me out a bit?

Comment: On the other hand, now we have a word that rhymes with "wisteria" :)

Comment: Good news for all the Desperate Housewives! lol

Comment: Incidentally, this is why you should always ask for the definition in a spelling bee.  It would be easy to tell that that the judge has the book open to "P" and not "F".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to wikipedia:

> Pfiesteria was discovered in 1988 by North Carolina State University researchers JoAnn Burkholder and Ed Noga. The genus was named after Lois Ann Pfiester (1936–1992), a biologist who did much of the early research on dinoflagellates. An in-depth story of the discovery can be found in And the Waters Turned to Blood by Rodney Barker.

According to Dictionary of American Family Names, Oxford University Press:

> Pfiester; German: variant of Pfister.

And, again, according to Dictionary of American Family Names, Oxford University Press:

> Pfister; South German and Swiss German: occupational name for a baker, from Middle High German pfister ‘baker’ (from Latin pistor).

Comment: Ah, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I thought so. When I read the question, I also wanted to find out what the heck it meant! :D

Comment: haha, likewise! :) What are words without meaning? letters I suppose...lol

Answer (score 1):

From [*And the Waters Turned to Blood*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PO6AFO) by Rodney Barker, p. 103:

"*Pfiesteria* was a tribute to their friend the late Lois Pfiester, a pioneer in unraveling the sexual life cycles of fresh-water dinoflagellates..."

Comment: ah, ok. That makes sense...Do you know Louise Pfiester's nationality, German perhaps?

Comment: @Mr_CryptoPrime - I typed her first name wrong (I'll edit my answer for posterity!) - it's "Lois", not "Louise".  Here's a [short biography](http://www.bookrags.com/tandf/pfiester-lois-ann-tf/).  She was born in Louisville, Kentucky - but I don't know her ancestry; probably German, but I'd need to do a bit more genealogical research (than I feel inclined to do...)

Comment: I will look around for a bit and tell you if I find anything.

Comment: That'd be excellent.